# Scroll a list while the user is dragging an object near the bounds

Tags: java, android

I have a problem that I have been unable to solve in a way that I am very happy with.

I have a view that I am dragging and dropping into a list. That list is created using a recyclerView. The drag object works fine, and the recyclerView's items can all receive the events no problem. Now I want to make the list scroll as the user drags their finger close to the top or bottom of the list. My first step was to add a dragEvent listener to the recyclerView, and attempt to start scrolling each time I got a location near the top or bottom edge. So, my DragEvent.Location case looks something like this:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION: {

            removeDragScrollCallBack();

            float y = event.getY();
            final int scrollAreaHeight = v.getHeight()/4;
            final int delayMills = 16;
            int scrollAmount = 0;

            if (y > v.getHeight() - scrollAreaHeight) {
                scrollAmount = 10;
            } else if (y < scrollAreaHeight) {
                scrollAmount = -10;
            }

            if (Math.abs(scrollAmount) > 0) {

                final int finalScrollAmount = scrollAmount;

                dragScrollRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if (canScrollVertically(finalScrollAmount)) {
                            scrollBy(0, finalScrollAmount);

                            if (dragScrollHandler != null && dragScrollRunnable != null) {
                                dragScrollHandler.postDelayed(this, delayMills);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                dragScrollRunnable.run();
            }

            return true;
        }
```

It kinda works. Things scroll in the right direction. It seems to sputter a bit though, and generally not scroll very smoothly. Additionally, the drag and drop drop event sometimes doesn't make it to the children while the recycler view is still scrolling.

So, I went to the google example of doing a similar thing in a using a list view - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q). I modified the code they used for their list view and tried to handle my recyclerView in a similar manner. This had even poorer results for me.

I have tried various other alterations of these techniques, and swapped to using the smoothScroll function instead of the standard scroll function, but I'm not too happy with any of the results.

Does anyone have a good solution for how to handle this?

Update: I now believe that many of my problems with this functionality are due to the drag listener being fairly unreliable. At sometimes the recycler fails to get events when it's children are receiving events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the drag listener on a view is not terribly reliable. At random times as I moved my finger around the screen, the drag listener wouldn't recieve all of the events. I believe the reason for this was the way that the children of the recyclerView were also recieving the on drag callbacks. The solution was to do what I had tried originally, but through a listener on the fragment itself. Now when I get an event, I check the coordinates to see what view it is in, and then convert it to local coordinates for that view. Then I can determine exactly how I need to handle it.